# Relationships among the terms "slope", "parameter", and "coefficient"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, definition

In $y=mx$, is $m$, are there different implications of referring to $m$ as a "slope", a "coefficient", a "parameter"? Or perhaps the "slope coefficient" or "slope parameter"?

For context, I am describing a the process of parameterizing a linear model (as opposed to trying to interpret a description). As I understand, slope is a type of parameter, but it is not clear if there is a difference between parameter and coefficient.

Comment: "Slope" is applicable since your model is a line (through the origin). "Parameter" and "coefficient" are more generic terms; either of those are fine for use in your context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In $y=mx$, $m$ is slope, coefficient of $x$ and a paramter as well. There are no different implications if for example you call it a "slope parameter" or "slope coefficient" or simply "slope". These are just convenient terms to avoid confusion. Conceptual implications are not different.